# How Social media analytics platfome get data from Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, social-media

I need to make something like [Quintly](https://www.quintly.com/), to get analysis from public pages on Facebook, like the number of funs, the number of reaction, # of comments, # of shares for each post ..., and i have to keep a daily historical evolution for each stat.

I could use Facebook Graph API, but it doesn't seem to me like a right idea, since it takes several minutes to fetch data from the API, Quintly gets one year data's in seconds.

Are there another solutions to get my needs ?

Comment: _“since it takes several minutes to fetch data from the API, Quintly gets one year data's in seconds”_ – which likely only just means that they have that data cached on their end already, instead of requesting it all every time ...

Comment: @CBroe yeah probably , do you think they are using Graph Api to fetch the data before the caching or is there another mehtode to do that ? like a premium Api, or they have a partnership with Facebook.

Comment: I doubt there's any official partnership; Facebook rather wants to push their own analytics tools I think. // They might be using the API - with enough clients, they could get a broad enough data set already by only allowed measures. If it's not that, then they must be scraping the info, which without Facebook's explicit prior written content is not allowed.